# Is it possible to create a variable data type in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm studying (slowly) x86 assembly and one thing I'd like to know is:

Is it possible for me to create a variable data type like a 16 byte integer?

Or do I only have access to db (8 bits), dw (2 bytes) and dd (4 bytes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which assembler you're using. For example, MASM also supports `DF` (6 bytes), `DQ` (8 bytes) and `DT` (10 bytes).

For larger variables, create an array or struct  (e.g.  `sixteen_bytes: DQ 2 DUP(0)`).

An example of using a struct/union in MASM:

```
LARGE_INT STRUCT
    UNION
        STRUCT
            LowPart dd ?
            HighPart dd ?
        ENDS
        QuadPart dq ?
    ENDS
LARGE_INT ENDS
```

You could then create an instance of `LARGE_INT` using:

```
foo LARGE_INT <>
```

And use it like:

```
fistp qword ptr foo.QuadPart  ; write to all 64 bits of foo
mov eax, foo.LowPart          ; read from the lower 32 bits of foo
; ..and so on..
```

Comment: Does it work in 32bits and 64bits? I mean, the DF, DQ and DT.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you're compiling a 32-bit or 64-bit application. The difference is which of them you can fit into a register (in the case of 16-byte variables, you'd only be able to fit them into the SSE registers).